# A messaging protocol to control a microcontroller over UART

Tags: protocols, microcontroller

I am looking for a light weight messaging protocol or structure that I can use to communicate simple data to control with a microntroller LEDS, LCD, etc over UART. I think I can send string ASCII data with such commands as "LED1 ON, LED1 OFF, LED1 GREEN, etc.."

I am using an Ethernet to RS232 (UART) module and I have an application that handles UDP data packets and parses them for specific data. This data from UDP then is used to control things such as turn on an LED, seven segment display, or LCD string message.

All the peripheral control such as controlling the LEDS, seven segment display, and LCD is handled by an AVR micro-controller. The architecture is almost like a master (Ethernet controller) and slave (AVR). However I also need to be able to get messages from the AVR such as button presses and heart beat messages.

I was thinking of sending something like

```
struct HWCtrlData
{
    unsigned char deviceID;
    unsigned char deviceDataLen;
    unsigned char deviceData[255];
}
```

So I could have a unique deviceID for each device I want to control, length of data, and the actual data.

I was thinking I can send ASCII strings to the RGB LED's, the seven segment displays, and LCD:

Send LED1 "Green" and it will turn the RGB LED to green for example.

Is there a better way to do this? Do I have to worry about ASCII strings and data corruption, error checking (CRC?)

Is there a protocol that already  exists that can do this for me?

Comment: The most widely used is [ModBus](http://www.modbus.org). But general concept of all protocols is `[ID:1-4][CMD:1-2][CMD_OPT:0-X][CRC:1-2]` (length in bytes).

Answer (score 0):

First what you should take care of is controlling of start and end of a packet. There are only two ways of doing it (if not use hardware flow control) Lets take Modbus protocol. It has two implementations RTU and ASCII. First detects end of a packet if a delay of 3,5 symbols occur between two consecutive bytes. Seconds uses start symbol 0x3A (:) for detection beginning of a packet.
First protocol is shorter but needs larger speed of MCU.

Use or not LRC, CRC checks depends on wire length and electrical environment. If you have errors, then you need control checks. RTU Modbus uses CRC while ascii uses lrc.

Do not use complicated strings in protocol, the simplest format looks like (for me) :[opcode][register][value] - 4 bytes only.

Answer (score 0):

Lots of ways to do it, ideally though you do want some sort of checksum and some way to distinguish the boundaries.  so start pattern (some character) length (probably a byte, binary), payload, checksum.  or start pattern, payload, checksum, stop pattern (some character/byte).

You can look at how NMEA does it which is all ascii.  there is a start pattern with actually a word, comma separated parameters if you need that, then a stop pattern then in ascii it has a checksum of the payload.  so you can see all of it in ascii, but it has all the desired features.

for yours you can probably get away with, a start pattern and a checksum, which could be ascii couple of digits. since your list of possible commands is likely short, they are sorta self checking.  not likely but you dont want an off to be missed and seen as on.  or have LED1 ON LED2 OFF, but some characters get lost and it comes in as LED1 OFF.  so the checksum would cover that.